# как сделать поиск через список

Tags: python

делал поиск по строке через find, но постоянно прибавлять  `or r.find("арбуз") != -1 or...` не очень удобно

нужно сделать поиск с списка, нашел решение:

```
a = ['арбуз', 'барабан', 'волк', 'гусь']

message= input()

if set(a) & set(message):
    print('В строке есть слова из списка')
```

вот только ничего не произойдет, если слово будет написано слитно с чем-либо

Comment: Приведите пример входного текста. Если у вас текст со знаками препинания (если вы имеете в виду, что слово может быть слитно со знаком препинания), можно вытащить слова регулярным выражением типа `re.findall(r"\w+", message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас беспокоит необходимость "постоянно прибавлять  or r.find("арбуз") != -1 or...", то решение простое, чтобы не возиться со слитностью вручную:

```
a = ['арбуз', 'барабан', 'волк', 'гусь']

message= input()

for word in a:
    if message.find(word) != -1:
        print (word)  # или другое нужное вам действие
```

Answer (score 1):

Переберите все слова из списка внутри [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
words = ['арбуз', 'барабан', 'волк', 'гусь']

message = input()
if any(message.find(w) != -1 for w in words):
    print('В строке есть слова из списка')
```

Можно решить задачу через регулярные выражения. [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) в этом случае ничего не делает, он пригодится если в список слов попадут когда-нибудь знаки препинания:

```
import re


words = ['арбуз', 'барабан', 'волк', 'гусь']
pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, words))

message = input()
if re.search(pattern, message) is not None:
    print('В строке есть слова из списка')
```

Comment: Станислав, спасибо. А `any` даёт какой-то выигрывш относительно `for word in a:    if ` или это просто запись покороче?

Comment: @Сергей, никакого заметного выигрыша я не ожидаю. Просто чётче выражена идея.